Why use useTransaction in preload but not in andWhereHas in AdonisJS(lucid orm)?
Can someone explain why useTransaction is necessary in the preload method but not in the andWhereHas method in AdonisJS?
I'm using AdonisJS 5.3 and couldn't find any documentation about this.
const person = await Person.query() .where('entity_id', entity_id) .preload('phones', (query) => query.where('phone', phone).useTransaction(trx)) .andWhereHas('phones', (query) => query.where('phone', phone).andWhereNull('deleted_at')) .useTransaction(trx) .first()
I tried not to use transaction and it doesn't work only andWhereHas uses the main transaction, I expected the query's useTransaction to also be passed to the preload
